# Best Language To Test/navigate other websites

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a website to assist me in testing my own sites.  My idea is the user (myself or another person in my team) could open up a site and then choose from a list of options what they would want to test.  Things such as new user sign up, log out, basic website functions... Etc.  Then would hit a submit button that would run a script with the selected input options.

The only criteria I have is that it must log all error logs and successes in some format that can be stored and reviewed later.

Would anyone have some suggestions on what language this would be the easiest to accomplish in?  I was thinking about Ruby or Python... But really up for any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: [travis](https://travis-ci.org)

Answer (score 3):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is a popular functional testing framework for automating browsers that has many language bindings.

If you use Selenium it will be easy to get help from the web since so many people/companies use it.

> Selenium is a suite of tools to automate web browsers across many
>   platforms.

Comment: I was about to post exactly this until I saw yours come up. +1 for Selenium

Comment: I had seen selenium before and was curious about it!  What would be a good language to use along with that can report its finds back to the original website?  I was thinking PHP might work well

Comment: After a google I found phpwebdriver (https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) so looks like that may be a good option. In my experience, Java has been a very popular option with Selenium. But a big selling point of Selenium is the many language/platform options it offers